# Get NaN as result in my age field after I select the date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate the age field but I keep getting NaN as the answer.
I had try to correct my code but I am still unable to detect the error. Can someone help me to point out the error? Appreciate the help very much.

```js
function getAge() {
  var dob = document.getElementById('DOB').value;
  dob = new Date(dob);
  var today = new Date();
  var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  document.getElementById('Age').value = age;
}
```

```html
<div class='input-group date' id='DOB' style="width:195px">
  <input type='text' class="form-control" name="DOB" id="DOB" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" onblur="getAge()" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>

<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:64px" id="Age" name="Age" value="" placeholder="eg. 21" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: Please inspect the values inside your function to determine what values are in them before calling new Date on them

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned the id `DOB` to the outer div as well as input field.
Change the id of outer div to something else and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have two elements with the same id="DOB". `document.getElementById('DOB')` will return the `div`. As such, `dob` is `undefined`, and the calculation gives `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!